# Date function in java

Tags: java, date, db2

I have two dates

1) from_date: eg. 01/01/2010 (1st January 2010)

2) present_date: eg. 05/06/2011 (5th June 2011)

I want the third date as:

3) req_date: eg. 01/01/2011(1st January 2011)

Year should come from "present_date" and day and month should come from "from_date".
The dates which I mentioned are hardCoded.
In my code, I run a query to get these 2 dates.

Comment: you want day and month from from_date and year from present date?

Comment: @ Rasel          yes..I want day and month from from_date and year from present date

Comment: Are these strings or a date class (Date/Calendar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from_date: for EX. 01/01/2010 (1 st January 2010)

present_date :for EX. 05/06/2011(5th june 2011)

String s1[]=from_date.split("/");
String s2[]=present_date.split("/");
String newDate=s1[0]+"/"+s1[1]+"/"+s2[2];
```

Comment: @MarrLiss:-Surely,he has to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the Calendar class
http://www.java-examples.com/add-or-substract-days-current-date-using-java-calendar

Something like // Untested

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(from_date);

Calendar cal2=Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTime(present_date);

Calendar cal3=Calendar.getInstance();
cal3.set(cal2.get(CALENDAR.YEAR),cal1.get(CALENDAR.MONTH),cal1.get(CALENDAR.DATE));

Date reg_date = cal3.getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set individual fields of dates:

```
Date req_date = from_date;
req_date.setYear (present_date.getYear());
```

Or, if you're using `Calendar` (`Date` is deprecated):

```
Calendar req_date = from_date;
req_date.set (YEAR, present_date.get(YEAR));
```

If they're strings, you can just use substringing to get what you want:

```
String req_date = from_date.substring(0,6) + present_date.substring(6);
```

(assuming `XX/XX/YYYY` as seems to be the case).

Comment: Unforutnately those methods are deprecated, so you'd better use `Calendar` (or Joda Time :) )

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean unusable, it just means it will be removed at some point. If your code is still using them (and they work okay), there's no need to convert to Calendar unless you need to since that may entail a lot of work. If you ever want to move to the latest and greatest Java after they're _removed_ then, yes, you'll have to do it then at the latest, otherwise YAGNI. In any case, I've provided the equivalents for `Calendar` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but this example should get you started:

```
int year = 2003;
int month = 12;
int day = 12;

String date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
java.util.Date utilDate = null;

try {
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  utilDate = formatter.parse(date);
  System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  System.out.println(e.toString());
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this way you can convert date Strings to java.util.Date object, then you can construct the third date by using Date/Calendar methods

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Date;

public class DateDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    }
}
```